# G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE() throws compiler error

Tags: gtk3, glib, gobject

I have written a programm in C and GTK3. I am using Arch Linux and everything works fine. However, I have to use my program also on a rather old Ubuntu machine.

- gtk+-3.0 3.10.8
- GCC 4.8.4

With this setup the program does not compile
In the Header file of a custom GTK-Widget I have:

```
#ifndef __LAYER_ELEMENT_H__
#define __LAYER_ELEMENT_H__

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
G_BEGIN_DECLS
G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE(LayerElement, layer_element, LAYER, ELEMENT, GtkListBoxRow)

/* Rest of file comes here */
```

When compiling it throws the error message:
**expected ')' before GtkListBoxRow** in the line with the G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE macro.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What's your version of glib?

Comment: It says 2.40.2-0ubuntu1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE` was added to GLib in version 2.44 (see [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html#G-DECLARE-FINAL-TYPE:CAPS)). If you want to compile on an old version of Ubuntu, you will either have to get hold of a backport of GLib 2.44 (or later) for that version of Ubuntu, and compile against that; or you will have to modify your code to not use any GLib APIs added after version 2.40.